# Linked list Generics java

Tags: java, list, generics

So i just started learning about java generics and my teacher gave us this code

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    class Node<T>{
        T info;
        Node<T> next;
    }

    Node<T> head = new Node<T>();
/*
and here are supposed to be all the methods like add,remove... that use Class Node
*/

}
```

so the problem is that on this line

```
class Node<T>{
```

Eclipse at `<T>` gives me the "The type parameter T is hiding the type T" warning
so i removed it and used

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
    class Node{
        T info;
        Node next;
    }

    Node head = new Node();
/*
and here are supposed to be all the methods like add,remove... that use Class Node
*/

}
```

and i get no warnings now but it made me wonder does the code do the same thing? and if it doesn't what is the difference? Could somenone explain the difference to me or point me to the right direction?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Remove the `<T>` from `Node<T>`, or make `class Node<T>` static.

Comment: Just think of it as a class level variable `hello`, and a local variable `hello`. 
Using `hello` where the local variable `hello` would be defined would acces the local variable `hello`, as you´d be accessing the `hello` defined within this scope. The same happens for `<T>` in `Node`, it would be a `<T>` in another scope, which just happens to have the same name as `<T>` defined in `LinkedList`, just having another scope and as though representing twp different `<T>` at different scopes, just that this happens at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much the same as having a local variable with the same name as a member variable, or a member variable in a subclass with the same name as one in the superclass: it's legal to do this, just confusing as to which `T` you are referring to.

You don't actually need the type variable on `Node`:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
  class Node {}
}
```

Because `Node` is an inner class of `LinkedList<T>`, it can use the `T` defined on the parent class. And this is what you want: the nodes of the list should be of a type related to the containing `List` (you won't have `Node<Integer>` in a `LinkedList<String>`, for example).

You can make `Node` static:

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
  static class Node<T> {}
}
```

Generics aside, this is good, because it means each of your `Node` instances aren't enclosing a reference to the `LinkedList` - you almost certainly don't need it.

Now they are separate type variables. But watch out here, it is now confusing as to which `T` you mean. You can make it clearer by calling the type variable something else - say, `S`. Then you can't mix up the types on the `LinkedList` with the types on the `Node`.

Comment: Thank you that was usefull but now when i make  `class node` static and replace the `<T>` with `<S>` i get the "S cannot be resolved to a type " error when trying to do `Node<S> head = new Node<S>()` or use `Node<S>` in any other way.

Comment: `Node<T> head = new Node<>();`. You use `S` inside the `Node` class, `T` inside the `LinkedList` class. It's the same way that you can't say `LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>()` outside the `LinkedList` class (well, unless you've got a type variable `T` in scope).

Comment: And another thing that i wanted to ask is. So what you are saying is that i could have a `LinkedList<String>` with `Node<Interger>` as elements ? is that viable and if it is why would i need to use something like that ?

Comment: "is that viable " Yes. "why would i need to use something like that" You almost certainly don't.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no `T` when your code is running. Generic type declarations are compile-time constructs at the time of Java 8.
Actual code will remove your generic type declaration altogether, and run without it.

As for the code you have, when you declaring inner non-static classes inside a class with generic type declaration, that inner class will use the same type as its outer class. This is why

```
class Node<T> {
  T value;
  Node<T> next;
}
```

is said to "hide generic type signature".

Answer (score 0):

Since the outer class is a Generic class, everything inside will depend on that value, inner classes don't need to specific a generic type if the outer class is already generic

Answer (score 0):

T is called as "bounded type parameters". so when you want restrict the  types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type. 
So below class bounded with type parameter.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
   class Node<T> {

              }
        }
```

Comment: *"T is called as "bounded type parameters""* So an unbounded type is called "bounded". That's funny.

Comment: I already did. `T` is not called "bounded" when it doesn't has any bounds.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Node` class is not declared as static, any `Node` object has an implicit reference to the `LinkedList` it was created within. Given this, the `T` type parameter declared in the outer class `LinkedList` is also used in the `Node` class.

For example, if you create a `Node` in the scope of a `LinkedList<String>`, it will implicitly be a `Node<String>`.

On the other hand, if the `Node` class was declared `static`, you would have to declare it as `Node<T>` (or any other symbol rather than `T`), because you couldn't use the `T` type from `LinkedList`.